# How is the "public/protected/private" method implemented, and how can I emulate it?

Tags: ruby, access-specifier

In ruby, you can do this:

```
class Thing
  public
  def f1
    puts "f1"
  end

  private
  def f2
    puts "f2"
  end

  public
  def f3
    puts "f3"
  end

  private
  def f4
    puts "f4"
  end
end
```

where now f1 and f3 and public, f2 and f4 is private. What is going on internally that allows you to invoke a class method that then changes the method definition? How can I implement the same functionality (ostensibly to create my own java like annotations)

for example...

```
class Thing
  fun
  def f1
    puts "hey"
  end

  notfun
  def f2
    puts "hey"
  end
end
```

and fun and notfun would change the following function definitions.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sometimes shove Ruby into an espressso cup.  Let's see how.

Here's a module FunNotFun...

```
module FunNotFun

  def fun
    @method_type = 'fun'
  end

  def notfun
    @method_type = 'not fun'
  end

  def method_added(id)
    return unless @method_type
    return if @bypass_method_added_hook
    orig_method = instance_method(id)
    @bypass_method_added_hook = true
    method_type = @method_type
    define_method(id) do |*args|
      orig_method.bind(self).call(*args).tap do
        puts "That was #{method_type}"
      end
    end
    @bypass_method_added_hook = false
  end

end
```

... that you can use to extend a class ...

```
class Thing

  extend FunNotFun

  fun
  def f1
    puts "hey"
  end

  notfun
  def f2
    puts "hey"
  end
end
```

... with this result:

```
Thing.new.f1
# => hey
# => That was fun

Thing.new.f2
# => hey
# => That was not fun
```

But see below the line for a better way.

---

Annotations (see normalocity's answer) are less trouble and, being a common Ruby idiom, will more easily communicate your code's intent.  Here's how to do it with annotations:

```
module FunNotFun

  def fun(method_id)
    wrap_method(method_id, "fun")
  end

  def notfun(method_id)
    wrap_method(method_id, "not fun")
  end

  def wrap_method(method_id, type_of_method)
    orig_method = instance_method(method_id)
    define_method(method_id) do |*args|
      orig_method.bind(self).call(*args).tap do
        puts "That was #{type_of_method}"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

In use, the annotation comes after the method is defined, rather than before:

```
class Thing

  extend FunNotFun

  def f1
    puts "hey"
  end
  fun :f1

  def f2
    puts "hey"
  end
  notfun :f2

end
```

The result is the same:

```
Thing.new.f1
# => hey
# => That was fun

Thing.new.f2
# => hey
# => That was not fun
```

Comment: @Semyon, Not if you have multiple threads adding methods to the same class concurrently.  Nearly always, adding methods is done by just one thread, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to write extensions to the Ruby language itself, which is possible. It's not something that can be explained briefly, but this link should get you started:

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html

This reference, having to do with annotations in Ruby, might also be helpful/relevant:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RubyAnnotations.html

Comment: Would it really be necessary to extend ruby for that to be possible? It feels like it should be doable with some clever metaprogramming or something, but I guess that may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure-ruby solution to get you in the right direction.  It hinges on `method_added`.  Be careful to avoid recursion by using a guard clause.

```
module Annotations
  def fun
    @state = :fun
  end

  def not_fun
    @state = :not_fun
  end

  def inject_label(method_name)
    state = @state
    define_method(:"#{method_name}_with_label") do |*args, &block|
      puts "Invoking #{method_name} in state #{state}"
      send(:"#{method_name}_without_label", *args, &block)
     end

    alias_method :"#{method_name}_without_label", :"#{method_name}"
    alias_method :"#{method_name}", :"#{method_name}_with_label"
  end

  def self.extended(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      def self.method_added(method_name)
        return if method_name.to_s =~ /_with(out)?_label\Z/
        @seen ||= {}
        unless @seen[method_name]
          @seen[method_name] = true
          inject_label(method_name)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Annotations

  fun

  def something
    puts "I'm something"
  end

  not_fun

  def other
    puts "I'm the other"
  end
end
```